# No input detected on primary screen at login

Tags: nvidia, multiple-monitors, login

After my DP cable moved slightly and the connection was lost, every time I boot into Ubuntu  20.04 the screen connected to the DP port goes to sleep, but I can still see the login screen on the secondary display. If I Ctrl+Shift+F1 into a TTY, log in and then Ctrl+Shift+F7 into the login screen again, the display starts working again.

I have tried installing the latest NVIDIA drivers (510) and changing the screen settings, but that didn't work.

Comment: Have you checked both ends of the cable for damaged pins?

Comment: The cable is new and the signal seems to be going through just fine (on Windows I get G-Sync and refresh rate up to 170 Hz with no issues)